# Clone a Properties object

Tags: java, properties, hashtable, clone

I'm a Java beginner so please bare with possibly silly questions.

I want to build a Properties object and then clone it. I need the clone to be a Properties object as well, as I need to apply methods to it that apply to Properties objects.

I have written the following code:

public class TryTask_B2 {

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Properties garList = new Properties();  // create "Properties" obj for 'Gar'
    Set gars;  // def a set for the 'Gar' keys
    String strGar;

    // Fill the "Properties" obj for 'Gar':
    garList.put("Gar_1", "rotura de lunas");
    garList.put("Gar_2", "arbitraje de ley");
    garList.put("Gar_3", "Adaptación del hogar");
    garList.put("Gar_4", "rotura de lunas");

    // Create clone of original "Properties" obj 'Gar':
    Object garList_clone = garList.clone();
    Set gars_clone;  // def a set for the cloned 'Gar' keys
    String strGar_clone;

    gars = garList.keySet();  // get a set-view of the 'Gar' keys
    Iterator itrGar = gars.iterator();
    gars_clone = garList_clone.keySet();  // get a set-view of the cloned 'Gar' keys
    Iterator itr_clone = gars_clone.iterator();

    Iterator itrGar_1 = gars.iterator();
    System.out.println("Original list of Gars: ");
    while(itrGar_1.hasNext()){
        strGar = (String) itrGar_1.next();  
        System.out.println(strGar + " : " + garList.getProperty(strGar) + ".");  
    }
    System.out.println();

    // Compare string-value entries for each and every key in the two lists:
    while(itrGar.hasNext()){
        strGar = (String) itrGar.next();  
        while(itr_clone.hasNext()){
            String str1 = garList.getProperty(strGar);
            strGar_clone = (String) itr_clone.next();  
            String str2 = garList_clone.getProperty(strGar_clone);
            boolean result = str1.equalsIgnoreCase(str2);
            System.out.println(strGar + " : " + str1 + ".");
            System.out.println(strGar_clone + " : " + str2 + ".");
            System.out.println(result);
            System.out.println();
            if(result != true){
            } else {
                Object garList_new = garList.remove(strGar);
                System.out.println("Removed element: " + garList_new);
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
        itr_clone = gars_clone.iterator();
    }

    Iterator itrGar_2 = gars.iterator();
    System.out.println("New list of Gars: ");
    while(itrGar_2.hasNext()){
        strGar = (String) itrGar_2.next();              
        System.out.println(strGar + " : " + garList.getProperty(strGar) + ".");  
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

}

but it gives me an error for applying the methods "keySet()" and "getProperty()" to my clone... Why?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is this line:

```
Object garList_clone = garList.clone();
```

You probably assigned the clone to an `Object` typed variable as this is the return type of the `clone` method.

But you (as the programmer) know that you are cloning a `Properties` object. So it is safe to assign the clone to a `Properties` typed variable. This also requires a cast:

```
Properties garList_clone = (Properties) garList.clone();
```

Afterwards you can call the methods that are defined for class `Properties`. The nature of your compile errors is that the copmiler only knows the declared type of your variables (here: `Object`). And you only can call methods on such a variable that are declared in that type.

Comment: Thanks, it works! But when I run it, I get the following exception message: run:
Original list of Gars: 
Gar_4 : rotura de lunas.
Gar_3 : Adaptación del hogar.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
Gar_2 : arbitraje de ley.
Gar_1 : rotura de lunas.

Gar_4 : rotura de lunas.
Gar_4 : rotura de lunas.
true

Removed element: rotura de lunas

 at trytask_b2.TryTask_B2.main(TryTask_B2.java:56)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: What does this exception message mean?

Comment: This is another problem. But you should not ask that as a question as there are plenty of [questions dealing with NPEs](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+NullPointerException).

Answer (score 1):

Because `Object garList_clone = garList.clone();` is an `Object` and not a `Properties`.

Change it from,

```
 Object garList_clone = garList.clone();
```

to

```
 Properties garList_clone = (Properties) garList.clone();
```